# C++ : How do I write a loop that takes two user prompted integers and prints the sum inclusive?

Tags: c++, loops

I misread an exercise from the C++ Primer, 5th Edition and thought that it said "Write a program that prompts the user for two integers. Print the sum of all numbers in the range between the two numbers". This isn't what it said but I am unable to do this. My last attempt is below. I am learning loops and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main() {

    int sum = 0, val = 0, v2 = 0;
    cout << "Enter two numbers separated by a space" << endl;
    cout << "Make sure the first number is smaller than the second" << endl;
    cin >> val >> v2;;
    cout << endl;

    while (val <= v2) {
        val += sum;
        ++sum;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try debugging this program (maybe even an online [debugger](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)). If you don't know how to debug (You **should** look up how to debug), add print statements in the `while` loop and see whether `val` and `sum` are changing as per your requirements.

Comment: If you enter `5` and `10`, instead of adding `5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10` your loop would be adding `5 + 1 + 2 + 3`.

Comment: `std::cout << (val + v2)  * (val - v2 + 1) / 2 << std::endl;` is sufficient you do not need a loop

Answer (score 0):

if loop is required

```
int temp = val; // keeping val unchanged
while (temp <= v2) {
    sum += temp;
    temp++;
}
```

Comment: temp, I take it, is a temporary variable?

Comment: Description of fix is dead wrong. Code looks about right, though.